# multiple form redirect only on first form's action

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have used multiple form in single page bcz i have to work my page without javascript enable in my browser..but problem is that all form redirect on single page..i.e all forms goes to first forms's action..if u can change 1st form action then all form goes to that link...i know there is silly mistake but i failed to figure it out..plz help me...thnks in advance..

```
//html code

<div id="propertymenu">
        <table cellspacing="20">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="mainainancebills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="PROPERTY DETAILS">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="inspectionreport.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="INSPECTION REPORTS">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD DOCUMENTS">
                </font>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="electricitybills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="ELECTICITY BILLS">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="OTHERS">
                </font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="expensestracker.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="DETAIL OF EXPENSES">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="mainainancebills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="MAINTENANCE BILLS">
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="ownerhome.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="submit" value="BACK">
                </form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: you have only 1 form. the 1st one. all others end with `</font>`.

Comment: @ashish kansara:-your form open and close is incorrect.all you require to open one by <form> and close </form> each one.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
</font>
```

instead of

```
</form>
```

in there a bit.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing is wrong in this code. because for every form there is not ending form is wriiten meant form is not close at every form start.
Your right code is

```
<div id="propertymenu">
        <table cellspacing="20">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="mainainancebills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="PROPERTY DETAILS">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="inspectionreport.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="INSPECTION REPORTS">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD DOCUMENTS">
                </form>
                </font>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="STATEMENT OF ACCOUNT">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="electricitybills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="ELECTICITY BILLS">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="downloaddocument.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="OTHERS">
                </form>
                </font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="expensestracker.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="DETAIL OF EXPENSES">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="mainainancebills.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $buildname; ?>" name="bn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $flatno; ?>" name="fn">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $area; ?>" name="area">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $pincode; ?>" name="pc">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $owner; ?>" name="owner">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $fullname; ?>" name="fname">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $email; ?>" name="email">
                    <input type="submit" value="MAINTENANCE BILLS">
                </form>
                </font></td>

                <td style="background-color:#94EEF2;">
                <form method="post" class='propertylist' action="ownerhome.php">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $property; ?>" name="pid">
                    <input type="submit" value="BACK">
                </form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please close form 1 by 1

```
<form name="Your_firstform">

//Your code here

</form>


<form name="Your_secondform">

//Your code here

</form>

<form name="Your_thirdform">

//Your code here

</form>
```